# Sampling marginal distribution from joint density

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, approximation, high-dimensional

Suppose we know that random vectors $x, y$ have joint density $p(x, y) \propto \exp(-U(x_1, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_n))$, and we want to draw a random sample from the marginal $p(x)$ (i.e. we want a random sample of $x$ but are not interested in $y$.)

Naively, we can do an MCMC on the jointly density $p(x, y)$, getting a joint vector $(x, y)$ and taking the $x$ part as the sample.  But when $n \gg m$, I speculate that this is not very efficient since we also draw a 'useless' sample of $y$, which we do not want. (e.g. papers like [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7392) indicate that the complexity of MCMC sampling scales polynomially with dimension)

Question: Are there better techniques to sample from $p(x)$ when $n \gg m$?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your $p(x, y) \propto \exp(-U(x_1, \ldots, x_m, y_1, \ldots, y_n))$.  If that is something special, you might be able to separate out $x$ and $y$

Comment: $U$ is not "something special". It is called the potential function of the distribution from which we intend to draw our sample. Ideally, $U$ is a strongly convex function $\mathbb R^{m+n} \to \mathbb R$; but there is no separability guarantee on $U$.

Comment: That is useful information: some people might otherwise read $U$ for *uniform*

Comment: If no separation or factorisation are available, I do not see a way out since the marginal is only defined by the joint and the $y$ component is not _useless_. Some savings may be found from [Rao-Blackwellisation](https://xianblog.wordpress.com/2021/01/06/rao-blackwellisation-in-the-mcmc-era/), though: Once a sequence of $(x_t,y_t)_{1\le t\le T}$ has been simulated from the joint, using the $y_t$ to approximate the marginal by$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^Tp(x|y_t)$$would work.